# Get list of all children from a repo in Jfrog though api

Tags: jfrog-cli

Is there a way through api, to get list of all the folders or children of a node in **JFROG** artifactory tool . For example I have following structure under a node Node N

```
 > A
 > B
 > C
```

is there a way if I ask all the children of node N I would get [A,B,C].

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `search` command to list all files matched to the input pattern:

```
jfrog rt s <search pattern>
jfrog rt s <repo>/<path to node N>/

# To show only direct children:
jfrog rt s <repo>/<path to node N>/ --recursive=false
```

More information can be found in the [documentation](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/CLI/CLI+for+JFrog+Artifactory#CLIforJFrogArtifactory-SearchingFiles).

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can retrieve the children using [api](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-FolderInfo)

Example:
https://Jfrog.example.com/artifactory/api/storage/examplerepo/examplefolder/

If not anonymous you may need to pass the credntials or token along with the request